# AWS Cloudwatch - Custom metric filter metrics doesn't appear in metric namespace

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I've created custom metric filters from my microservices logs (deployed on AWS EKS) in AWS Cloudwatch console which set the value of these metrics to 1 if an ERROR log has been found.
I want to use these metrics to create an alarm when a microservice starts producing ERROR logs.

I've successfully created one metric filter for each microservice (each metric has value 1 when a log with ERROR level is found) and now I want to use these custom metrics for creating alert.
The problem is that the custom metrics are not visible and selectable inside the metrics namespace, so I'm not able to create any alert.

Only one of the custom metrics I've created is visibile and selectable inside the metrics namespace: this metric is the only that has matches after the creation (ERROR logs were produced after the custom metric filter creation).

Any suggestion about it? I've not found nothing yet about this issue.
It seems strange to me that I've to force ERROR logs inside my microservices to be able to create alarms, I want to create them even if no match has occurred.

Comment: You should add a default value to your metric filter. That should allow the metric to be visible to the alarm quicker (that helped me in the past)

Comment: That happens to me every time I create a new custom metric. What I have found is that you have to wait before CloudWatch "sees" the new metric. I'm not sure exactly how long you have to wait, but more than say 10 minutes, but probably less than a couple hours.

Comment: @Caldazar your suggestion is right. It was not a problem of time interval before Cloudwatch sees the new metric as suggested by Cloudlady. Thank you both!